# Windows workflow is not detecting runnable instances after calling Delay activity

Tags: instance, delay, detection, workflow-foundation

Since of last week we have a problem in our production env. Everytime a workflow instance is delayed, after calling the [Delay activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activities.statements.delay?view=netframework-4.8), it is never resumed by WF.

We are running a WF service hosted in IIS, targeting .NET framework 4.6.1. The workflows are long running and the sqlWorkflowInstanceStore is a SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU3).

The problem only occurs in production, where we have 4 different IIS servers (instance owners) running our WF service.

When we run SQL Server Profile, we can see that sp [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[DetectRunnableInstances] isn´t called in  production, however it is called in the other environments, where everything works.

Not sure these are relevant, but here are our sqlWorkflowInstanceStore config settings (same settings are used in all environments):

```
<sqlWorkflowInstanceStore connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=WwfPocSQLPersistenceStore;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=True" 
                                      instanceEncodingOption="None" 
                                      instanceCompletionAction="DeleteAll" 
                                      instanceLockedExceptionAction="BasicRetry" 
                                      hostLockRenewalPeriod="00:00:30" 
                                      runnableInstancesDetectionPeriod="00:00:02" />
<workflowIdle timeToUnload="0" />
```

We can see all our idle instances in the [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancesTable] with the PendingTimer column set to values that are expired.

We have no errors in our logs, and I believe (?) nothing is failing. But for some reason our SqlWorkflowInstanceStore application is not polling the instancestore db to see if there are runnable instances. I have found nothing in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/instance-activation) as to what would cause the lack of polling after runnable instances.

I have compared the .NET framework and SQL Server versions between failing and none failing environments and not found any differences.

What could be the cause of this mess causing our entire production system to collapse?

Does anyone know if MS have release the WF code as open source?

Answer (score 1):

I´ll just answer my own question in case it helps somebody out there.
The issue was, of course, corrupted instances in the instancestore. How they became corrupted is unclear, though it happend after a deployment during heavy load (not recommended).
we reproduced the error by first restoring a backup of the instancestore on localhost. Then we truncated table [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].RunnableInstancesTable.
Then we manually loaded the instances into [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].RunnableInstancesTable one by one, by calling sp exec [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].InsertRunnableInstanceEntry. Whenever a corrupted instance was loaded, the communication with the instancestore store, which could be seen by running a profiler.

This took us 4 working days to figure out..

Comment: thank a ton your post, this issue took more than 2 weeks for investigating and solving

Comment: Thank you very much for the info... indeed.... persistange storage corrupted. thanks

Comment: We may have a similar situation. Unfortunately, in the answser a verb is missing in the last sentence... :) the communication with the instance store did what? What could be seen in the profiler?